# Are there anyways to speed Greenplum up?

Tags: greenplum

I have 3 vms(one master two segment hosts of the opensource version), each has 32 cores 64 threads and the memory of 251G.
There is one big table,which have nearly 70 fields and one hundred million records.
The parts of definition as follows:

```
with (appendonly=true,compresslevel=5)
distributed by(record_id) partition by range(dt_date)
(partition p201012 start ('2021-01-01'::date) end ('2021-01-31'::date) every ('1 days'::interval))
```

The culster have 30 primary segments and 30 mirror segments.
Both insertion(<2000 records/s) and selection(about 25s) are too slow,since we have one hundred million records a day and more than one second is not allowed.

**So my questions are: is there anyone using Gpdb? Are there anyways to speed it up?**

Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that you have way too many primaries/mirrors (30) for that few cpus on the system.   The general rule of thumb is 3-4 cpu/vcpu per segment (i.e., postgres database).  Your system should be reconfigured to only have 2 primaries per host to better utilize the cpu and memory on the hosts; 1 might even be better with that small amount of memory on the segment hosts.

As it stands now, you are swamping the system with too many databases trying to utilize too few system resources.

Jim

Comment: Thank u for you advice.  I made  one master two primary segments at the beginning, I found the query time reduced while I increased more segments.  that's why the 30 primary segments come about.

Comment: All the write operations need to be spread out to all your segments, that's why the INSERTs are so slow. And you still only have 3 VMs, which means 3 physical I/O channels at best, and one physical I/O channel if everything runs on the same host.